# My Max-Width to 100% does'nt fill the entire page to begin making responsive design

Tags: html, css, web

Hi,

So Here is my code, I am trying to get a better grasp on web design without using other ways of making a site like setting margins left or right to a negative value state (Ex: `margin-left: -10px`).

I have a header in the head tag where inside the header it has a div called "mainBanner" but when i try to set the Max-width to fill the entire page, it fills it BUT leaves out about 10% white space margin outside the banner.

Code:

```
 <header>
 <div id="mainBanner">
    <img src="logo.png">
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
 body {
background-color: #d7d7d7;
      }
 #mainBanner {
background-color: #663333;
height: 90px;
width: auto;
max-width: 100% auto;
margin-top: -1%;
border-bottom: 3px solid #402225;

  }
```

What did i do wrong ? Usually i set in the #mainBanner tag in css to something like

```
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: -10px;
```

to fill in those gaps. But i been told that is'nt good practice to a beginner web designer making responsiv web design for the first time. Any better way to do this ?

Comment: Try changing `width: auto;` to `min-width: 100%;`

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0` to the CSS for the `body` element.

Comment: I get something like this with these methods http://imageshack.com/a/img823/3326/y6wc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost All The browser set 10px of margin in the body tag byDefault

The body margin is that problem

Here the best this to do is a global reset

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is also compatible with responsive design ? because my site will be also rendered in mobile browsers so last thing i would want it to happen is an error but it definetly works :) cheers and let me know

Comment: It will be, but that will remove margins on all elements on your sites. Some that should have some. While it works as an answer, but please read some more about CSS resetting.

Comment: Actually it will not but it is vulnerable to bugs, not to worry if it happens replace the " * " with " html, body " but the best idea for here is a reset

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the margin your browser sets on the `body` tag by default:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Body tag has its own margin you should use some fix for example

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While, I think you should accept the guys above answers, as that most likely is your problem. Then I'm going to give you a quick CSS reset code aswell.

```
html {color: #000000; background: #FFFFFF;}
html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
input, select, textarea {outline: none; border: none;}
table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
fieldset, img {border: 0;}
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;}
ol, ul {list-style: none;}
caption, th {text-align: left;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-size: 100%; font-weight: normal;}
q:before, q:after {content: ''; content: none;}
abbr, acronym {border: 0; font-variant: normal;}
sup {vertical-align: text-top;}
sub {vertical-align: text-bottom;}
input, textarea, select {font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit;}
input, textarea, select {*font-size: 100%;}
legend {color: #000000;}
```

If you use this in your projects, that most of the cross-browser related issues should be **nulled** and you can set them yourself. This is the reset code, that I use on all of my sites. There are of course more complex reset codes, but this usually is enough for basics.

Also, as a side note, did you write correctly that your `<header>` element is inside the `<head>` element? Because, thats not how its supposed to be. In the head keep your scripts and etc, but visible html to the user, must be inside `<body>`.